# How to take a nice screenshot with Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to take a screenshot of a given website without scrolling down.

I'm using Selenium WebDriver for automation and I'm using **Chromedriver**.

**Problem 1**: I have noticed that when my driver runs and opens the chrome browser, it opens the browser with a small size. I tried the following but couldn't know how to set it to **maximum** and not take the scroll wheel on the right in the screenshot (see image below).

**Problem 2**: I want to block any chatbots or cookies so that I can take a clean screenshot (see image below).

The following is what I have tried.

```py
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

options.headless = False  # don't know sure what this does!
options.add_argument("--window-size=1700,1000")
options.add_argument("disable-popup-blocking")

options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
                      "profile.default_content_setting_values.cookies": 2
                  }
)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

URL = 'https://apploi.com/'

driver.get(URL)
sleep(1)

driver.get_screenshot_as_file('apploi.png')

driver.quit()
print("end...")
```

Desired screenshot output is to look like this:

[image]

Comment: i believe after you initialize the driver, you can do something like `driver.maximize_window()`. I dont know how to get rid of the popups though. and headless mode opens the driver without opening an actual window, so the window is open, but in the background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) `pytest` test that will do all that:

```py
from seleniumbase import BaseCase

class MyTestClass(BaseCase):
    def test_screenshot(self):
        self.open("https://apploi.com/")
        self.remove_element("[data-nosnippet]")
        self.save_screenshot("my_screenshot.png")
```

Save that to a file, and run it with `pytest` after installing `seleniumbase`.

Comment: And full disclosure: I'm the maintainer of https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain better your code, please?

Comment: It opens the URL. Removes the cookie message at the bottom. And then saves a screenshot as ``my_screenshot.png`` in the folder where you called ``pytest``. You can also add additional options such as ``--headless`` mode, which can make the screenshot bigger.

Comment: This is an interesting package. I tried it with this website https://www.staffingsoft.com/ but didn't work due to `[data-nosnippet]`.

Comment: That's a different website, so you can remove the ``self.remove_element("[data-nosnippet]")``.

Comment: I see. But I have a bunch of websites. How can I know when to set it and when not?

Comment: Depends on whether the element is present on the other sites. You could use an ``if`` statement to check. ``if self.is_element_present("[data-nosnippet]"): self.remove_element("[data-nosnippet]")``.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247400/discussion-between-joe-and-michael-mintz).

Answer (score 0):

import By

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
```

add this to maximize your screen

```
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
```

to remove cookie permission

```
cookie = driver.find_element(By.ID,'hs-eu-cookie-confirmation')
        driver.execute_script("""
        var element = arguments[0];
        element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
        """, cookie)
```

and lastly, add this to take screenshot

```
driver.save_screenshot("screenshot.png")
```

by the way you can remove this line. by default headless is false.

```
options.headless = False  # don't know sure what this does!
```

you can't run headless mode on that website